# Proof using induction

Tags: trigonometry, induction

I have no clue how to even start this:
Proof using induction for every $k=1,2\dots n$

$$\vert\sin\sum_{k=1}^nX_{k}\vert\leq\sum_{k=1}^n\sin X_{k}$$

edit: Sorry, I also know this: $$0\leq X_{k}\leq\pi$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try your base case:
$$|\sin(X_{1})|\le \sin(X_{1})$$
In fact for this case we have equality, since $0 \le X_{k}\le\pi$, so that $0\le\sin(X_{k})\le 1$

Now assume, for $n=N\in \mathbb{N},$ that $$\sum_{k=1}^{N}\sin(X_{k})\ge|\sin(\sum_{k=1}^{N} X_{k})|$$
Then, adding $\sin(X_{N+1})$ to both sides, 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{N+1}\sin(X_{k})\ge|\sin(\sum_{k=1}^{N} X_{k})|+|\sin(X_{N+1})|$$
since $\sin(X_{k})\ge0,$ so $\sin(X_{N+1})=|\sin(X_{N+1})|$
But, then, using the triangle law: $$|a|+|b| \ge |a+b| \implies |\sin(\sum_{k=1}^{N} X_{k})|+|\sin(X_{N+1})|\ge|\sin(\sum_{k=1}^{N} X_{k})+\sin(X_{N+1})|$$
Now observe that, since $|\cos(y)|\le 1$ for all $y$, multiply each term in the modulus by the cosine of something just makes it smaller. Motivated by our goal, and the sine addition formula, we do the following:
$$|\sin(\sum_{k=1}^{N} X_{k})+\sin(X_{N+1})|\ge|\sin(\sum_{k=1}^{N} X_{k})\cos(X_{N+1})+\sin(X_{N+1})\cos(\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k})|$$
But this final term in the modulus is simply $$\sin(\sum_{k=1}^{N}X_{k}+X_{N+1})=\sin(\sum_{k=1}^{N+1}X_{k})$$so
$$\sum_{k=1}^{N+1}\sin(X_{k})\ge |\sin(\sum_{k=1}^{N+1}X_{k})|$$
And the proof is complete by induction.

Comment: Thanks! I have one question:
How from this:$$|\sin(\sum_{k=1}^{N} X_{k})|$$
When you added $N+1$  ,you got this:$$| \sin(\sum_{k=1}^{N} X_{k})|+|\sin(X_{N+1})|$$ 
Shouldn't the $X_{N+1}$ be inside the $\sin$?

Comment: We did not 'add N+1', we added $\sin(X_{N+1})$ to both sides - in other words, we just added a number to both sides, which doesn't change the inequality.